# Redirection with nginx in VirtualBox

Tags: nginx, redirect, virtualbox

I'm currently trying to redirect all access from http to https on a nginx serv in VirtualBox.

When using a test machine in VirtualBox, everything is working perfectly.

My issue is with port redirection on VirtualBox.

I want to be redirect directly from my host machine.

For the moment when I access https it's fine, but when I try to access the http, I'm redirected to the nginx serv address in Virtualbox.

My ssl conf is :

```
server {
listen 443 http2 ssl;

server_name _;

ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_tickets off;


add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

root /var/www/html;

location {
proxy_pass http://loadbalancing;
try_files $uri $uri/ =404
}
server {
listen 80;
server_name _;
return 301 https://srv.dmz.lan   
}

upstream loadbalancing {
server srv1;
server srv2;
}
}
```

Dmz is a NAT network under VirtualBox with those redirections:

[image: listes des ports]

Comment: Please share the relevant parts of your nginx config

Comment: in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf

Comment: Not the path, but the content. Show how the redirect is configured compared to the usual routing.

Comment: yes i understood, i just wanted to be sure before editing the post